# Pass view as parameter to Button triggering it as a Modal

Tags: swift, button, struct, modal-dialog, swiftui

I'd like to have a custom button struct that receives a view as a parameter that will be shown as modal when the button is clicked. However, the view parameter is always empty, and I can't find the mistake I'm doing. My button struct looks like that:

```
struct InfoButton<Content:View>: View {
    @State private var showingInfoPage: Bool
    private var infoPage: Content
    init(infoPage: Content, showingInfoPage: Bool) {
        self.infoPage = infoPage
        _showingInfoPage = State(initialValue: showingInfoPage)
    }
    var body: some View {
      return
        Button(action: {
               self.showingInfoPage.toggle()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
         }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showingInfoPage) {
            self.infoPage
        }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .topTrailing)
    }
}
```

This button is placed in a navigation bar from a template I'm creating for multiple other views.
I think the most relevant parts of that template are these:

```
protocol TrainingView {
    var title: String { get }
    var subheadline: String { get }
    var asAnyView: AnyView { get }
    var hasInfoPage: Bool { get }
    var infoPage: AnyView { get }
}

extension TrainingView where Self: View {
    var asAnyView: AnyView {
        AnyView(self)
    }
    var hasInfoPage: Bool {
        false
    }
    var infoPage: AnyView {
        AnyView(EmptyView())
    }
}
struct TrainingViewTemplate: View {
    @State var showInfoPage: Bool = false
    @State var viewIndex: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
//the views that conform to the template
        let views: [TrainingView] = [
            ExerciseView(),
            TrainingSessionSummaryView()
        ]
        return NavigationView {
                ViewIterator(views, self.$viewIndex) { exerciseView in
                    VStack {
                        VStack {
                            Text(exerciseView.title)
                                .font(.title)
                                .fontWeight(.semibold).zIndex(1)
                            Text(exerciseView.subheadline)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                            Spacer()
                            exerciseView.asAnyView.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        }
                    }.navigationBarItems(trailing: (exerciseView.hasInfoPage == true ?  InfoButton(infoPage: exerciseView.infoPage, showingInfoPage: self.showInfoPage) : nil))
                    
                }
            }
}
```

I debugged to the point, where the navigationBarItems are initialized. At that point, the exercise view has content for "hasInfoPage" and "infoPage" itself.

One exemplary Exercise View has a header like that:

```
struct ExerciseView: View, TrainingView {
    var title: String = "Strength Session"
    var subheadline: String = "Pushups"
    var numberOfExercise: Int = 1
    @State var ratingValue: Double = 0
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var hasInfoPage: Bool = true
    var infoPage = ExerciseDetailView()
```

So in this view, the infoPage gets initialized with the ExercieDetailView() which I receive in the TemplateView, but as soon as the InfoButton is clicked, the debugger shows an empty infoPage, even though the "showingInfoPage" variable contains the right value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't confirm to protocol, so default `infoPage` from `extension TrainingView` is shown.

The solution is

```
struct ExerciseView: View, TrainingView {
    // .. other code here

    var infoPage = AnyView(ExerciseDetailView()) // << here !!

``
```